# Increase space on RAID 10

Tags: mdadm

I have a RAID10 with 7 working devices ,4 actives and 3 spares .I want to increase the RAID's space from 4 devices to 6 .

i use this :

```
sudo mdadm --grow --raid-devices=6 /dev/md0
```

but it gives me this message :

```
mdadm :insufficient head-space for reshape on dev/sdb1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How did you configure your original raid10 array?  Did you first set it up as a 4-drive array?  If so, you may need to first add one more drive to your array before you can grow it.

Take a look at this post: [Grow LVM Raid10?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/grow-lvm-raid10/117586#117586)

Apparently you can grow a raid10 array with mdadm 3.3 and linux 3.5 (or later), but with a caveat:

> It is possible to extend a RAID10 across additional PVs, *but they must be added in multiples of the original RAID10*

Hope this helps!  Let me know if it works for you.  I'm planning to create a raid10 array with 2 drives initially (I think that's only possible in Linux, not hardware raid), and hope I don't run into any problems when trying to grow it later.

Answer (score 1):

Tested expanding a raid-10 on a ubuntu 16.04 VM

Setting up 4-disk raid-10

```
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME    SIZE FSTYPE TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      10G        disk 
├─sda1    8G ext4   part /
├─sda2    1K        part 
└─sda5    2G swap   part [SWAP]
sdb      10G        disk 
└─sdb1   10G        part 
sdc      10G        disk 
└─sdc1   10G        part 
sdd      10G        disk 
└─sdd1   10G        part 
sde      10G        disk 
└─sde1   10G        part 
sdf      10G        disk 
└─sdf1   10G        part 
sdg      10G        disk 
└─sdg1   10G        part 
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
mdadm: layout defaults to n2
mdadm: layout defaults to n2
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: size set to 10475520K
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo pvcreate /dev/md0
  Physical volume "/dev/md0" successfully created
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgcreate vgdata /dev/md0
  Volume group "vgdata" successfully created
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvcreate -n data -l 100%FREE vgdata
  Logical volume "data" created.
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/vgdata/data 
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Creating filesystem with 5236736 4k blocks and 1310720 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 9d1b530f-76c8-49d1-be9b-b020039554f7
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done   
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/vgdata/data /mnt/
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ echo test | sudo tee /mnt/test
test
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid10 sdd1[3] sdc1[2] sdb1[1] sde1[0]
      20951040 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Expanding to 6-disk raid-10

```
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1
mdadm: added /dev/sdf1
mdadm: added /dev/sdg1
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid10 sdg1[5](S) sdf1[4](S) sdd1[3] sdc1[2] sdb1[1] sde1[0]
      20951040 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --grow --raid-devices=6 /dev/md0
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid10 sdg1[5] sdf1[4] sdd1[3] sdc1[2] sdb1[1] sde1[0]
      20951040 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [>....................]  reshape =  1.9% (415872/20951040) finish=0.8min speed=415872K/sec

unused devices: <none>
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo pvresize /dev/md0
  Physical volume "/dev/md0" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vgdata/data
  Size of logical volume vgdata/data changed from 19.98 GiB (5114 extents) to 29.97 GiB (7672 extents).
  Logical volume data successfully resized.
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/vgdata/data
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem at /dev/vgdata/data is mounted on /mnt; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 2, new_desc_blocks = 2
The filesystem on /dev/vgdata/data is now 7856128 (4k) blocks long.
cladmin@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/mapper/vgdata-data   30G   44M   28G   1% /mnt
```